# Hola alguien sabe porque el primer printf si se introduce un valor superior a 20, sale el siguiente printf pero despues se acaba el codigo de repente

Tags: c

Este codigo es la entrada a un cajero para sacar dinero
el primer printf pide la cantidad de dinero que se quiere sacar, el segundo el dinero que habia en el banco y el tercero el dinero que queda una vez has sacado dinero
los else if se utilizan para deteerminar la cantidad de billetes que se van a dar

[image: el primer printf pide la cantidad de dinero que se quiere sacar, el segundo el dinero que habia en el banco y el tercero el dinero que queda una vez has sacado dinero]
[image: los else if se utilizan para deteerminar la cantidad de billetes que se van a dar]
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola por favor evita compartir el codigo en imagenes, mejor compartelo por texto

Comment: Hay 2 problemas con las imagenes. Primero, a algunos nos cuesta leerlas. Segundo, nos impide que copiemos el codigo y lo probemos en nuestra maquina. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta.